# igraph 1.0 cannot plot trees in mode "in"

Tags: r, igraph

The tree layout of `igraph` (1.0.1) doesn't work properly when trees are "in" instead of "out". For instance, these trees are properly plotted if no layout is used:

```
library(igraph)

# Create tree graph. Vertex 1 is root.
tree <- graph.empty(15)
tree <- tree + path(5,4,3,2,1)
tree <- tree + path(8,7,6,5)
tree <- tree + path(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,5)

# make_tree is new in igraph 1.0
tree.in <- make_tree(20, 3, mode="in")
tree.out <- make_tree(20, 3, mode="out")

par(mfrow=c(1,3))

### No layout
plot(tree, 
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1)
title("tree")

plot(tree.in, 
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1)
title("tree.in")

plot(tree.out, 
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1)
title("tree.out")
```

[image: trees]
However, if the tree Reingold-Tilford layout is called, then it can only plot the `tree.out`

```
### Tree layout
plot(tree, 
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1, 
     layout=layout.reingold.tilford(tree, mode="in"))
title("tree")

plot(tree.in, 
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1, 
     layout=layout_as_tree(tree.in, mode="in"))
title("tree.in")

plot(tree.out, 
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1, 
     layout=layout_as_tree(tree.out, mode="out"))
title("tree.out")
```

[image]

For the first two, the error is:

> Error in match.arg(arg = arg, choices = choices, several.ok =
>   several.ok) :    'arg' should be one of “out”

Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug of `igraph`?

**IGRAPH 0.7.1**:

In igraph 0.7.1 this example works fine:

```
tree <- graph.empty(15)
tree <- tree + path(5,4,3,2,1)
tree <- tree + path(8,7,6,5)
tree <- tree + path(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,5)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(tree, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1)
title("no layout")

plot(tree, 
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1, 
     layout=layout.reingold.tilford(tree, mode="in"))
title("layout")
```

[image]

Comment: According to its help page, `layout.reingold.tilford` is a deprecated layout function in `igraph` version 1.0.1. It seems to be replaced with `layout_as_tree` function, which is entitled `The Reingold-Tilford graph layout algorithm`.

Comment: But note that  `layout_as_tree` does not work either.

Comment: Maybe time to report this as an issue through the [igraph issue tracker](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues), after checking it wasn't already reported.

Comment: I think it is a bug.

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/113